# Can't import product names/descriptions with special characters

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to import a product CSV which has Bulgarian product names/descriptions (using the standard import under import/export->import)

The only way I've been able to import any so far is by wrapping them in quotes or by putting roman characters in front of the Bulgarian.

e.g. 'Ламинирани ПДЧ' or xxx Ламинирани ПДЧ

without adding these characters it outputs the error: Required attribute 'name' has an empty value in rows: 1

It seems like the Bulgarian is being stripped out completely? My file is encoded as UTF-8 and I've also set the default charset as UTF-8 in the htaccess file.

Is it possible to import the Bulgarian without quotes/roman characters?

Comment: Are you looking for a programmatic solution? Or just how to make the import work using Magento?

Comment: Ideally I'd like it to work with magento out of the box as you'd think it would, but If there's a programmatic solution to this that'll work for me too.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming-related Q&A site. Questions asked here should be specifically about programming. If you want a general Magento question answered you should post on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Ok, I'll post there, but if anyone has experienced this before and has a  programmatic solution then i'm all ears..

Answer (score -1):

I haven't personally tried it, but I have seen [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131078/importing-product-names-with-special-characters-using-magmi) that seems to work.

Try saving your csv file through Libre Office Calc with UTF-8 and try import again.

Comment: Try this link for more details. [Solution Link] (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131078/importing-product-names-with-special-characters-using-magmi)